# core data - insert new object with two entities

Tags: ios, core-data, insert, save

I have two entities with a to-many relationship, there can be multiple items to each list.

- List
- Item

Basically all I want to achieve is to to save an Item to a specific List on click.

I've figured out how to save a new list:

```
- (IBAction)handleBtnAddList:(id)sender

{ MyListAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
  NSManagedObject *newList;

newList =  [NSEntityDescription
           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List"
           inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newContact setValue:@"Shopping" forKey:@"name"];

NSError *error;
[context save:&error]; }
```

But how do I save an item to the newly created list "Shopping" ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

Hi there, finally had a chance to try this out.   It's working now but running into another issue. I can add a new list, but can't seem to add an item.

I looked in the sqlite database and under the 'Item' entity the column named 'zLists' is empty.  How do I get a value in there that will correspond with the 'List' that the item should be under?

This is what I've got

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *list = [NSEntityDescription
                                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
[list setValue:@"Test List" forKey:@"name"];
NSManagedObject *item = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
[item setValue:@"Test Item" forKey:@"name"];
```

I also tried adding this at the end but it crashes the app

```
[item setValue:@"Test List" forKey:@"lists"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For my example to work with your code, you will need these prerequisites...

1. You have a Core Data model `NSManagedObjectModel`,
2. Within that model, you have an entity `List`,
3. Within that model and for that entity, you have two attributes `listDate`, and `listText`,
4. You have used Xcode to prepare (or have manually prepared) an `NSManagedObject` subclass for your entity `List`.

Instead of your line of code: `[newContact setValue:@"Shopping" forKey:@"name"];`...

you might choose to use dot notation to set attribute values in this manner...

```
newList.listDate = [NSDate date];  //sets the attribute to current date and time
newList.listText = <<some user input from (for example) a view controller>>;
```

or to match your syntax, you might choose to use key-value coding in this manner.

```
[newList setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"listDate"];
[newList setValue:<<some user input>> forKey:@"listText"];
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply. I'll try this now.

Comment: Saving a List works now. However can't seem to save an Item. I've edited my question with details...